# Fluctuation-dissipation theorem for the acoustic equation

Tags: thermodynamics, acoustics, fluctuation-dissipation

Recently I discovered a [paper](http://asa.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1121/1.2713673) by R. Snieder on the extraction of the acoustic Green function from cross-correlations of the acoustic noise. What differs this paper from other papers on the subject, is that here the volume-distributed random sources are not neglected in computations (often, only surface-distributed sources are taken into account). It is also shown that in many important cases they can not be neglected; for example, when the attenuation is sufficiently big.

However, in order to relate the Green function to the cross-correlation of acoustic noise in the presence of volume-distributed random sources, the author makes quantitative a conjecture that I never encountered before in acoustics. He tells that the *in conditions of thermodynamic equilibrum, the power spectrum of the random sources must be proportional to the imaginary part of compressibility* (and, as a corollary, to attenuation). I don't find the justification persuasive, but the article has more than 100 citations and this assumption appears in the following papers by the other authors.

For me, this assumption is an important form of a fluctuation-dissipation theorem. In view of this, I would like to know, if the above-mendioned relation of the power spectrum of noise and imaginary part of acoustic compressibility was already strictly derived by means of statistical physics, or whether it was already checked experimentally?